# Add a common folder to both of my modules using Maven

Tags: java, maven

I have a Maven build that has two modules (Server / Client) and I wish to create a folder containing shared methods by both of them.

What should I add to my `pom.xml`(s) in order to have a successful build?
I have 3 poms, a parent one in the root of the project, and two other ones respectively in the `server` folder and the `client` one.

Here is my parent `pom.xml`:

```
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.christopher.kade</groupId>
  <artifactId>jcoinche</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <name>jcoinche</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <modules>
    <module>client</module>
    <module>server</module>
  </modules>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
      <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId> <!-- Use 'netty-all' for 4.0 or above -->
      <version>4.1.6.Final</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should place the classes you in client and server in a third module.
and then add a dependency to that in the client and server modules.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something similar to this. Within your main(parent) pom.xml, add the module and its dependency.

```
<modules>
 <module>client</module>
 <module>server</module>
 <module>jcoinche-common</module>
</modules>

<dependencies>
..
..
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.christopher.kade</groupId>
   <artifactId>jcoinche-common</artifactId>
   <version>${project.version}</version>
   <!--       ^=== assumes same version as project      -->
</dependency>
..
..
```

Then, in your submodules that require the jcoinche-common module, just add a dependency there as well:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.christopher.kade</groupId>
   <artifactId>jcoinche-common</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Thats it.